# SQL table with a column which may have "multiple types of NULL" values

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

The title may be confusing so I need to clarify.

I have the following survey dataset that I need to transfer to a PostgreSQL database.

```
| id | title | income | age    | height | weight | Education   |
| 1  | foo   | 10000  | 45     | 170    | 50     | College     |
| 2  | bar   | 15000  | -20000 | -30000 | 45     | High School |
| 3  | hoge  | -10000 | -10000 | 150    | 60     | -20000      |
| 4  | fuga  | 20000  | 20     | -10000 | 70     | College     |
...
```

Where -10000, -20000, and -30000 all represent a null value, but due to different reasons.
(e.g., -10000 means that the participant was not shown the question about the column, -20000 means the participant skipped the question, and -30000 means they made an invalid answer.)

The question is, how to design a table and constraint to model this situation?

Obviously, if I use INTEGER for income and other columns and use VARCHAR for education the null values will not be identical. Also, if I treat income as a mere INTEGER, the "null" values will be just a negative number which will be problematic in the following data manipulation.

Comment: What is the problem with just using `NULL` for these certain negative values?

Comment: I need to distinguish "why the value is null" in further data analysis.

Comment: For the person whose recorded height value is `-30000`, what does that represent, and also, what was the original value for the height?

Comment: It represents that the participant input an invalid value (e.g., -200). I don't have the original value.

Comment: @kemakino . . . The question is really how you are going to USE the data.  It is quite possible that you want user-defined types or an entity-attribute-value model to represent this.

Comment: I wanted to learn what kind of approaches exist indeed. EAV seems a possible solution, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best design here would be to just add status columns for each data column, assuming you want to keep track of the status for a given column.  Something like this:

```
| id | title | income | age    | age_code | height | height_code | weight | Education   |
| 1  | foo   | 10000  | 45     | 1        | 170    | 1           | 50     | College     |
| 2  | bar   | 15000  | NULL   | 2        | NULL   | 4           | 45     | High School |
| 3  | hoge  | NULL   | NULL   | 3        | 150    | 1           | 60     | NULL        |
| 4  | fuga  | 20000  | 20     | 1        | NULL   | 5           | 70     | College     |
```

Here, I am using the code values 2,3 to represent some sort of error code in the age, and the values 4,5 represent other types of errors with the height.

Typically the values in a column should represent just one thing.  In this case, the age and height columns should store data for those measurements, not the status of those measurements.  I backfilled `NULL` values for where the data be missing or otherwise totally invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we set 2 and 3 to both in age_code and height_code? Why did you distinguish them?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use different status codes for the various columns.  This was my assumption when I answered.